# Error while fetching gem metadata when creating a new project on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, new-operator

I have some problem and after one day searching for the answer I didn't find anything useful.
There's the problem :

When I want to create a new project with rails by typing this :

```
~$ rails new project
```

I get some messages and then an error message :

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please report this error to the Bundler issue tracker at https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues so that we can fix it. Please include the full output of the command, your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. Thanks!
```

Do you have solutions ?
Thanks for the answers !

EDIT : Using rails 3.2.2, rubygems 1.8.19 and bundler 1.1.1

Bastien

Comment: which rails version you use ? Can you paste the Gemfile ?

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.2, but where can I find the gemfile ?

Comment: in directory create by rails new project.

Comment: There's the Gemfile : http://paste.awesom.eu/BastienDuplessier/OD4&ln

Comment: which rubygem and bundler version are you ?

Comment: I have rubygem 1.8.19 and bundle 1.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I put it here just in the case of somebody had the same problem.
In fact, it was a problem with openssl witch make the whole thing fail.

```
 cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
```

After many researchs, I found my answer here :

http://www.dinduks.com/rails-cannot-load-such-file-openssl

Thank you all for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

Try to update rubygems and bundler gem.

Comment: It looks like this issue was fixed in https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1666 but may be reopened if it is still reproduced. 
Please include full output when you run rails new project

Answer (score 0):

Just install jruby-openssl:

jruby -S gem install jruby-openssl

Just an advice: read all your console log, the answer was there.

Comment: Yes, it was here since the beginning ;) Thanks